Manim/python overwrites update function, animating only last updater
I am attempting to make a Manim animation where dots follow a set of radial basis functions as a function of x. I've also made a vertical line that the dots should follow exactly. Strangely, the dots appear to overlap each other, making it look like only one dot is in the animation. Using pdb.set_trace, I saw that the updater function in each Dot gets changed in each iteration of the for loop. deepcopy of either the function or the Dot object does not seem to prevent this from happening. What do I do to have a different updater function for each of these Dots?
from manim import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
import pdb


class RDFBasis(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        axes = Axes(
            x_range=[0, 5, 1],
            y_range=[0, 1, 0.2],
            x_length=10,
            tips=False,
        )
        axes_labels = axes.get_axis_labels()

        vt = ValueTracker(0)
        line = Line(axes.c2p(0, 1), axes.c2p(0, 0))
        line.add_updater(lambda x: x.move_to(axes.c2p(vt.get_value(),  0.5)))

        graphs = []
        dots = []
        anims = []
        for i in np.linspace(0, 5, 5):
            func = lambda x: norm.pdf(x, loc=i, scale=0.5)
            graph = axes.plot(func, color=RED)
            graphs.append(graph)

            dot = Dot()
            dot.move_to(graph.get_start())
            dot_mover = lambda x=dot, graph=graph: x.move_to(graph.get_point_from_function(vt.get_value()))
            dot.add_updater(dot_mover)
            dots.append(dot)
            # pdb.set_trace()


        plot = VGroup(axes, *graphs)
        labels = VGroup(axes_labels)
        # pdb.set_trace()
        self.add(plot, labels, line, *dots)
        self.play(vt.animate.set_value(5.0))


I'm not a python expert, so I'm not sure why this happens, but the lambda in the for loop somehow breaks the graph.get_point_from_function() function. Replacing your code with sth like this will make it work:
...
func1 = lambda x: norm.pdf(x, loc=1, scale=0.5)
func2 = lambda x: norm.pdf(x, loc=2, scale=0.5)
func3 = lambda x: norm.pdf(x, loc=3, scale=0.5)
    
funcs = [func1, func2, func3]

    
    for i in range(3):
        graph = axes.plot(funcs[i], color=RED)
        graphs.append(graph)
        ...

